# Handle concurrent requests on a action method .net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

There is a ASP.NET MVC Action Method that redirects to a specific page, but also another method redirecting to another page. If both methods were hit at same time - how can I instruct C# to redirect only to first method URL. It shows that first method is hitting in debugger but second method hit after and redirects to last hit URL.

How can I redirect only to first hit method?

i have a ajax request that get hit every 5 secends.and hit signout method if not authenticated.

```
  function Authenticate() {

                            ajax = $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "/EmployeePortal/Dashboard/Authenticate",
                                data: "q=123",
                                success: function (isAuthenticated) {
                                    if (!isAuthenticated || count > 360) {

                                        window.location.replace("/PortalAccount/SignOut");
                                    } else {
                                        count++;
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
```

also i have a link to sign out manually that hit the same method.but with a id to identify it separately.

```
  public virtual ActionResult SignOut(string id)
    {
        object obj = new object();

        lock (obj)
        {
            if (!id.IsEmptyOrNull())
            {
                ClearSession();

                return Redirect(ConfigSettings.Current.CurrentConfigSetting.SignOutRedirectUrl);
            }
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        ClearSession();
        ActionResult loginAction = MVC.PortalAccount.Login();
        return RedirectToAction(loginAction);

    }
```

Problem is sometimes when i hit the signout manually. The 5 seconds one will hit the same time and it will redirect to wrong page. how can i avoid that

Comment: Can you provide some code samples? If you're `return`ing, then it can only happen once. But I'm not sure how you're doing it.

Comment: One idea would be to disable the sign out link once you start the ajax call and enable it again after the ajax call completes.

Comment: Another idea would be to create a separate method for each signout.

Comment: creating separate method didn't helped me because separate method also get hit same way after first one and redirect to wrong one.